# Spring and pendulum massive bob trajectory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

This is essentially a better formatted version of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222970/if-a-spring-at-a-90-degree-angle-from-a-wall-with-a-weight-at-the-end-where-wil) which was put on hold (also by myself), mainly for being a HW&E question without any research effort by the OP and poor formatting.

I tried solving the problem, but don't seem to be able to and want to pose it as a new question.

[image: Ball, spring and wall.]

A mob of mass $m$ is connected to a massless Hookean spring of length $L_0$ and constant $k$, itself connected by a frictionless hinge at $O$ to a vertical wall. At $t=0$ the bob is released with the spring horizontal and unstressed.

*What's the trajectory of the bob and its speed when it impacts the wall?*

I tried several approaches without avail:

1. Cartesian free body diagram and force balances to set up equations of motion in $x$ and $y$-directions. That became very complicated due to the expression of extension of the spring.
2. Cartesian Hamiltonian: same problem.
3. Polar coordinates Hamiltonian: that got very complicated after time derivation.

The most promising seems setting up equations of motion in polar coordinates.

$O$ is the origin, the horizontal through it the polar axis and $\theta$ the angle. $R$ is the distance of the bob to $O$.

For the equation of rotation I get:

$$mgR\cos\theta=mR^2\ddot{\theta}$$

$$g\cos\theta=R\ddot{\theta}...\text{Eq.1}$$

For translation along the line of the spring, I get:

$$mg\sin\theta-F_s=m\ddot{R}$$

$$F_s=k(R-L_0)$$

$$mg\sin\theta-k(R-L_0)=m\ddot{R}...\text{Eq.2}$$

$\text{Eq.1}$ and $\text{Eq.2}$, *if correct*, would be a system to two non-linear DEs.

But is it and if so, how to proceed from there?

Comment: You've shown work, but where's the conceptual question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: perhaps there isn't one. Perhaps it's a case where rotation and translation seem to create a difficult combination. I'm asking to leave this question to stand unflagged for a bit and see if some one can at least throw some light on it. I maybe wrong but easy this is certainly not. One could argue that 'why doesn't Hamiltonian with time derivation not work here?' is conceptual.

Comment: A rigid pendulum with large deflection already has an intractable equation of motion. I can't see it getting better by adding the spring...

Comment: @Floris: I have to say that that thought also occurred to me: no small angle approximation here. Does the rigid pendulum with large deflection has numerical solutions that we know of?

Comment: A pretty complete analysis is given at http://depts.washington.edu/amath/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/leah_ganis_pres.pdf (50 pages). I don't vouch for its accuracy - but take a look.

Comment: @Floris: Thanks, will peruse that tomorrow. Do you think my EoMs are correct?

Comment: Yes they looked OK but again I just glanced at them; then I thought "surely somebody has solved that" so I used my google-fu. Working on reduced clock cycles due to cold medicine... so no hard physics for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form you have for the equation of rotation holds if $R=$const., otherwise it is necessary to account for $\dot R \neq 0$.

In polar coordinates, as you have, the tangential velocity is $v_\theta = R\dot\theta$, so for tangential motion we have instead
$$
mg\cos\theta = m\dot v_\theta = m R\ddot\theta + m\dot R\dot\theta
$$

---

This given, let's check that energy is an integral of motion. Multiply the above by $R\dot\theta$,
$$
mgR\dot\theta\cos\theta = mR^2\dot\theta\ddot\theta + m R\dot R \dot\theta^2
$$
and rearrange as
$$
mgR\frac{d}{dt}\sin\theta = \frac{1}{2}mR^2\frac{d}{dt}\dot\theta^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\frac{dR^2}{dt}\dot\theta^2\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left(mgR\sin\theta\right) - mg\dot R\sin\theta = \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m R^2\dot\theta^2\right)\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m R^2\dot\theta^2 - mgR\sin\theta\right) = - mg\dot R\sin\theta 
$$
Get rid of the rhs by using the radial equation
$$
m\ddot R = mg\sin\theta + k(L_0 - R)
$$
multiplied by $\dot R$. This gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m R^2\dot\theta^2 - mgR\sin\theta\right) = - m\dot R\ddot R + k(L_0 - R)\dot R\\
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m R^2\dot\theta^2 - mgR\sin\theta\right) = - \frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac{1}{2}m \dot R^2 + \frac{1}{2}k(L_0 - R)^2 \right)
$$
Rearranging again leaves us with
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \frac{1}{2}m \left(R^2\dot\theta^2 + \dot R^2\right) - mgR\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}k(L_0 - R)^2 \right] = 0
$$
Recognize that $R^2\dot\theta^2 + \dot R^2 = \dot{\bf r}^2 \equiv v^2$ is the instantaneous velocity squared and the above reduces to
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left[ \frac{1}{2}mv^2 - mgR\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}k(L_0 - R)^2\right] = 0
$$ 
as expected. Moreover, given that the initial energy is null, we actually have
$$
\frac{1}{2}m \left(R^2\dot\theta^2 + \dot R^2\right) - mgR\sin\theta + \frac{1}{2}k(L_0 - R)^2 = 0
$$

---

At this point I don't think this is an integrable system. I only know that eventually one could obtain an EOM in terms of $R$ only from the energy conservation eq. above and the EOMs. Not sure this would help in regards to something tractable though, but didn't look much into it either.

Comment: Referring to the this video: [Swinging spring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPUB0ICVqIA) it appears that after a steady state is reached $R$ is maximum at the equilibrium and minimum at the ends, keeping this in mind and referring to the diagram above, can we make a approximate a relation such as $R=k\theta$, for some constant $k$?

Comment: @udv: thank you for pointing out the error of my ways. Sapere Aude! :-)

Comment: @Vishwaas: thanks for the video. What would be worth looking at is the system at low $\theta$.

Comment: @Gert Welcome .

Comment: @Vishwaas: I can't see anything against $R\sim\theta$, it could work. The case of small $\theta$ mentioned by Gert is worth a look too, but I would actually go for both small $\theta$ _and_ small deviations of $R$ from $L_0$ (as independent variable). Note that even in this case the EOMs remain nonlinear and nontrivial due to the $\dot R \dot\theta$ coupling, so the dynamics could be pretty interesting.

Comment: @Vishwaas: On a second thought, given how $\theta$ is defined the small deviations should be relative to $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dot R\dot \theta$ would be 2nd order in deviations. So the thing to consider is the dynamics around $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and the spring's equilibrium length $R_0 = L_0 + \frac{mg}{k}$, either linearized or to 2nd order in deviations.

Comment: Small deviations about $\theta_0 = \frac{\pi}{2}$ would probably work, still I doubt there's a closed solution, nice answer though, thank you udrv. I find it interesting how a simple pendulum can be solved and a simple spring can be solved, but not the combination! And thank you @Gert

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. I set up the problem in polar coordinates with $\theta$=0 defined as pointing downward and wrote down the Euler-Lagrange equations. Since udrv already cranked through much of the math, I'll just state the results below for the two equations:

$g m r(t) \sin (\theta (t))+2 m r(t) r'(t) \theta '(t)+m r(t)^2 \theta ''(t)=0$
$-g m \cos (\theta (t))+k (r(t)-\text{$r_0$})+m r''(t)-m r(t) \theta '(t)^2=0$

Mathematica couldn't find an analytical solution for this pair of coupled differential equations, but it was able to numerically solve the equations using the initial conditions r(0)=$r_0$, r'(0)=0, $\theta$(0)=$\pi$/2, and $\theta$'(0)=0 when given particular numerical values for $r_o$, m, g, and k.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by $\theta=0$? Does this mean $\theta=\pi /2$ with the 'old' $\theta$? Also, what was the outcome? Remember, the question really concerns itself with only part of the trajectory: until the mass *first* crosses $y$, that is 'old' $\theta > \pi /2$. For +10 creds. :-)

Comment: Yes, $\theta$=$\pi$/2 corresponds to the 'old' $\theta$=0. I redefined $\theta$ so that it agrees with the definition of $\theta$ commonly used for standard rigid pendulum problems. If I had been able to find an analytic solution, I would have posted that but offhand I don't see any such solution or any way to simplify the problem further. I just tossed the Euler-Lagrange equations up here in case anyone wants to investigate the problem further.